# just copying catkin_ws/src from other,and catkin_make causes 'can't find *.h'

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I built new system for computer A, so I copied my working version of catkin_ws/src from the computer B. during the copying process, i occluded src/CMakeList.txt, i did 'catkin_init_workspace' to make new CMakeList.txt for the new system. After simple copying the files, i did first catkin_make, source /devel/setup.sh, installing all required dependency.
A, B both have same OS(ubuntu vivid) and same ROS(jade), So i didn't expected issues.
But when i do 'catkin_make' it cause below messages which said that it can't find header file. What can cause this kind of issue? if i want to move source file, should i care more than simply copying file?

```
[ 11%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSOutput3DWrapper.cpp.o
/home/isnl/catkin_ws/src/lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSOutput3DWrapper.cpp:28:46: fatal error: lsd_slam_viewer/keyframeGraphMsg.h: No such file or directory
 #include "lsd_slam_viewer/keyframeGraphMsg.h"
                                           ^
compilation terminated.
[ 12%] Building CXX object lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/src/IOWrapper/OpenCV/ImageDisplay_OpenCV.cpp.o
lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/build.make:560: recipe for target 'lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSOutput3DWrapper.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/src/IOWrapper/ROS/ROSOutput3DWrapper.cpp.o] Error 1
make[2]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:4160: recipe for target 'lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [lsd_slam/lsd_slam_core/CMakeFiles/lsdslam.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:127: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make -j4 -l4" failed
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/224723/just-copying-catkin_ws/src-from-other,and-catkin_make-causes-%27can%27t-find-*.h%27/) by [jinhwan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25685/jinhwan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2016-01-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jarvisschultz](https://answers.ros.org/users/1272/jarvisschultz/) on 2016-01-22**:
Are your workspaces in the same location on both machines? If not, CMake caches could be retaining incorrect information. It's probably a good idea to delete the `build/`, `devel/`, and `install/` directories in the workspace on the new machine. Then source the jade setup.bash and run `catkin_make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks to me like a custom message isn't being built.  Check to make sure that your IOWrapper package CMakeLists.txt has a dependency on lsd_slam_viewer_generate_messages_cpp.  [Here](http://answers.ros.org/question/52744/how-to-specify-dependencies-with-foo_msgs-catkin-packages/) is another question that explains how to properly build messages from separate packages.

---

Originally posted by [superjax](https://answers.ros.org/users/20144/superjax/) with karma: 51 on 2016-01-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0